# Adding DLL to project reference

Tags: c#, mysql, dll, dllimport

I am creating an hello word application for MySQLConnection in my windows mobile device using compact framework. 
I have downloaded the mysql dll from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

To add the DLL , i placed the dll inside the debug folder(tried placing anywhere in the project structure ) and by right clicking project reference and then add reference and browsing to the dll file .

Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace MySQLSample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private MySqlConnection conn;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

When i run this i get ,

```
Error   3   The type 'System.ComponentModel.Component' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.   H:\Vijay-Workspace\Samples\MySQLSample\MySQLSample\Form1.cs 17  33  MySQLSample
Error   4   The type 'System.Data.IDbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.    H:\Vijay-Workspace\Samples\MySQLSample\MySQLSample\Form1.cs 17  33  MySQLSample
```

[image]

Comment: I have already added system.data . I have added an picture that contains the list of all dll files i have

Comment: According to the errors you are getting, your MySQL dll is looking for .NET v1 versions of `System` and `System.Data`: Are you sure you have downloaded the proper version of the MySQL .NET libraries?

Comment: Oh Okay . I will try a different version of mysql.dll

Comment: I found out the problem Mysql is not available for my windows ce mobile . So it happens .  Is there any other databases that can be used instead of sqlce in windows ce mobile devices ?

Comment: You can use SQL Server Compact or SQLite